# Using FunctionTransformer in Python Pipeline to apply individual funtion to y_train

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, gridsearchcv

I am using sklearn Pipelines and would like to include an outlier filter in the pipeline that cleans y_train. Yet I am missing the last piece in my code which enables me to have my individual function applied not to the features but y_train. Can you help me apply the function IQRcap to my GridSearchCV pipeline as I am currently getting the error invalid syntax?

Here is my code (assuming that X_train, y_train, X_test, and y_test are already loaded and defined):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import xgboost as xgb

def IQRcap (x):
    Q1 = x.quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = x.quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    Max= (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)
    Max= round_down (Max)
    if Q3 > 0:
        x.values[x>Max] = Max


pipe = make_pipeline([(FunctionTransformer(IQRcap(y_train)), xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror'))])

gbm_param_grid = {
    'xgb_model__min_child_weight':[1, 2],

}

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, gbm_param_grid, cv=5)

grid.fit (X_train, y_train)
print ("Best cross-validation accuracy> {:.2f}".format(grid.best_score_))
print ("Test score: {:.2f}".format(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print ("Best parameters: {}".format(grid.best_params_))
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a dedicated transformer for transforming target in regression problems: [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html#sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor). It should do the job.